# Mount cd, cd not found when Installing komplete vst on ubuntu

Tags: sound, software-installation, mount, wine, vst

I'd like to know if any of you know how to use  komplete vst from Native instrument on ubuntu. this page : https://www.native-instruments.com/en/support/knowledge-base/show/707/using-native-instruments-hardware-under-linux/ says that it should work on linux so I downloaded the free windows files but I didn't manage to make those work.
There is an iso file opened the iso file with the disk image mounter and opened the exe inside which opened in wine. Then it at some point during the installation process a dialog opens with "insert . "

[image]

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of that dialog box.

Comment: @Raphael done uploading

Answer (score 1):

The iso is being detected by Ubuntu, but not by wine. To get it detected by wine do the following:

1. Right-click on the mounted partition then, goto properties.
2. See the path to your mounted iso. It should be something such as `/mnt/path/to/`.
3. Now, open wine, then, Applications -> Wine -> Configure Wine.
4. Under the Drivers tab, click Add.
5. Set path to `/mnt/path/to/` as before.
6. Set type as cdrom.

Your iso should be detected by now.

Comment: I'm not sure that was the problem because wine was opening the exe. I anyway, there was a little folder to install sub elements of komplete, some worked. So I'll keep trying your solution tomorrow but it didn't seem to be the root issue.